# Hibernate Dynamic @Where clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am having @Where at @Table level.

I need to get rows with EffDate field less than current date.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="party")
@Where(clause="EffDate < " + currentdate())
public class Party implements Serializable {
.......
}
```

I understand @Where takes constant expression which needs to be provided on compile time. But I need to compare with current date from Java and not from Database.

Any Idea how can I do that.

Comment: JPA has no such `@Where` annotation

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton. Updated the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL function/constant for the current timestamp (depending on the type of database it might be called e.g. `current_timestamp`) (note however, that since this will be plain SQL, it will use the timestamp from the database server, not the server where the Java application runs on:

```
@Where(clause="EffDate < current_timestamp")
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I need it from Java application and not from Database.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [Hibernate filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) and enable it by default for all Sessions in the application. Depending on which framework you use for transaction management, you can add an interceptor/hook that enables the filter when transactions are started.

Answer (score 0):

@Where annotation will not work, since it accepts constant expressions. Instead, I use findOnByEffectiveDateLessThanEquals from JPARepository.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation